# Draggable plugin bug on auto-scroll (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

I am working in a project that uses jquery draggable plugin to move widgets (divs) to another place in the page, but I'm having a problem that I'm not being able to solve it.

My problem is exactly the same that occurs in the jquery draggable plugin demo site: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#scroll

If you start dragging the first div and then you move it to bottom you will notice that the windows scrolls (as it is expected). But you can see that the offset of the mouse between the div and the mouse isn't the original. I mean, the div should be near the mouse not far while you are scroll down (or up).

I have tried some options as the use of

```
{ refreshPositions: true }
```

for the draggable element or even

```
{ cursorAt: { left: 0, top: 0 } }
```

but both solutions don't solve the problem.

Thanks for your time.